# Windows Phone Wallet Make A Payment/ What Can I Use NFC For

Tags: 8.0, wallet

I thought getting the Lumia 920 with NFC would allow me to make mobile payments with my visa card. Was I totally wrong in this assumption?  I hate asking a broad question, but I'm grasping to find the usefulness of a 'wallet' feature.  Is the wallet and nfc capability a completely useless feature, or is there support coming for making payments at Walmart/McDonalds/etc?  I see the samsung android nfc ads, and it seems totally pointless, is that really the functionality windows phones are limited to (send a photo to someone)?

To add details to what Thinn had to say:
http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/201841-nfc-payments-not-supported-t.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to launch, Microsoft did announce that they were definitely going to allow NFC payments via the phones. In my experience though, there doesn't seem to be many stores that accept NFC payment *yet*, and those that do are severely limited in the maximum transaction amount. It may also be the case that your bank/carrier is yet to complete whatever they need to do to allow for NFC payments via your phone.

Comment: Thank you.  I was really hoping this was going to be a wallet killing feature, but what a bummer, at least for now :\

Comment: I should also point out that whilst I'm in the UK, stores near you may move to NFC faster...

Comment: AT&T doesnt allow the use for NFC Transaction payments. Had the same problem today so i called them and thats what they told me

Comment: I was able to make nfc payments on my galaxy s3 but not on my Lumia 1520 with 8.1. I have att as my carrier.

Comment: @casey It seems you have a new question - you should [ask it as such](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), rather than as a comment.